# Implement Search in Mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

Problem: Want to implement A search using like or Rlike that should pass the below mention testcases/scenarios.

I am using Mysql version 8

If My user search for keyword : ABC 218
All the rows having data like

1. ABC218
2. ABC-218 XXXX
3. ABC 218 XXX

But it should not get the data for row having data like

- ABC XXX YYYY 218 //as there some extra word between my keywords

Note: All searching is case insensitve.

I tried below Mention query

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE summary RLIKE '\\bABC[-*%].?218.*' AND id = 1;`

Here is sometestcases for reference

Test case 1

```
 Keyword : ABC 218
 Expected resut : should match the row
```

Test case 2

```
keyword : ABC-218
Data: ABC 218 demonstrated 
Expected resut : Columns having above mention data should came in results.
```

Test case 3

```
Keyword : ABC-218
Data: ABC218 demonstrated 
Expected resut : Columns having above mention data should came in results.
```

Test case 4

```
Keyword : ABC218 demonstrated
Data: ABC218 demonstrated 
Expected resut : Columns having above mention data should came in results.
```

Test case 5

```
Keyword : ABC218 demonstrated
Data: ABC 218 demonstrated 
Expected resut : Columns having above mention data should came in results.
```

Test case 6

```
Keyword : ABC-218 demonstrated
Data: ABC218 demonstrated 
Expected resut : Columns having above mention data should came in results.
```

Test case 7

```
keyword : ABC 218 demo
Data: ABC218 demonstrated 
Expected resut : Columns having above mention data should came in results.
```

Test case 8

```
keyword : ABC-218 demo
Data: ABC218 demonstrated 
Expected resut : Columns having above mention data should came in results.
```

Test case 9

```
keyword : ABC-218 demonstrated
Data: ABC218 demo-nstrated 
Expected resut : Columns having above mention data should came in result.
```

Along with - my query should also ignore space, hyphen, comma. Semi-colon, percentage, back or forward slash

I tried below Mention query SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE summary RLIKE '\bABC[-*%].?218.*' AND id = 78681;

Comment: Why then use `.`? Try just `'\\bABC[-\\s,;%\\\\/]?218\\b'`. Here, `[-\\s,;%\\\\/]?` is used to match an optional "*space, hyphen, comma. Semi-colon, percentage, back or forward slash*". Also, if `2189` is not be matched, `\\b` on the right is required.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the help :). I added a new test case no 9 it is not working with that.

Comment: Why? What is the problem?

Comment: it is failing test case number 9, or i have might done a typo could send me syntax with that it would be a really helpfull

Comment: ``SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE summary RLIKE '\\bABC[-\\s,;%\\\\/]?218\\b'``

Comment: Make sure to "blacklist" columns & fields to make sure not to accidentally let people search in sensitive fields. (lets say customer adress or unhashed passwords (not that you should have those))

Comment: So does it work as expected? If not, please specify the *exact* input and *exact* expected behavior. Note the my suggested regex finds a match in `ABC218 demo-nstrated`, so I really do not get it why you say Ex. 9 does not work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes i when i am exectuing this query ```SELECT * FROM table WHERE summary RLIKE '\\babc218[-\\s,;%\\\\/]?demo[-\\s,;%\\\\/]' AND id = 78681;```

when coulmn have data like ABC-218 demo-nstrate  and search keyword is abc-218 demo. in this case it is not working

Comment: Now, I am not sure what you are asking about because this string is quite different from the others. `'(?i)\\babc[-\\s,;%\\\\/]?218[-\\s,;%\\\\/]?demo'` [will work](https://regex101.com/r/teMHDS/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i am asking because i am kind of implementing  a free text search in that use can enter any search keyword in any manner my job is to deliver result by ignoring spaces - , and all that stuff for stactic keyword we can do by twisting condition little bit. but i can not assure where to put  [] logic if user type abc218 together there is some data in column like abc-218 should get.i hope you get idea and again thanks for your valuable time and efforts .:)

Comment: Put `\\W*` between each character. `'\\ba\\W*b\\W*c\\W*2\\W*1\\W*8`. `\W` matches any non-word char. Or use `[-\\s,;%\\\\/]?` / `[-\\s,;%\\\\/]*` instead if you only allow these chars.

Comment: So what are you doing and trying to achieve? Please give more details in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

For *that* example, I would have a `FULLTEXT` index on the column and do

```
WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST("ABC 218 ABC218")
  AND col REGEXP "\\bABC.?218\\b"
```

Notes:

- It will be fast (due to `FULLTEXT`)
- It will cover the cases where any one character optionally exists between the two parts.
- If you want to limit the separator, use `REGEXP 'ABC[- ]?218'`.  (The "-" must be first in the "character set".)
- It will fail for some keyword due to `FULLTEXT` limitations (min token len, stop words, etc).
- You must split 'ABC218' before formulating the `AGAINST`.
- Tests 8 and 9 imply that "218" is irrelevant and can be left out.
- "case insensitive" -- Check that the `COLLATION` for the column ends in `_ci`.  (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: the main problem is with regex we can not create a generalized regex like <<regex>>abc218 <<regex>>, we have to put regex at a particular position in our example we can archive desired result by placing regex like this abc<<regex>>218 but if user typed abc218 as combine keyword we can not identify where to put regex.

hope you understand problem @Rick James

Comment: That's why I put the `[- ]?` in my regexp.

Comment: Part numbers (and similar things) are a big mess to search for.  I have not found a good answer.